# R - quote substitution

Tags: r, math, expression

I write an expression in R and need then to differentiate it.
I wrote:

```
> foo <- quote(x+y)
> bar = quote(foo + z)
```

and I need to "x+y+z", but get "foo + z"

Please, help me

Comment: How about this? `substitute(foo + z, list(foo = quote(x+y)))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try `bquote`:

```
foo <- quote(x+y)
bar <- bquote(.(foo) + z)
# > bar
# x + y + z
```

Answer (score 1):

We could also do

```
library(rlang)
library(glue)
foo <- "x + y"
glue("{foo} + z") %>%
    parse_expr
# x + y + z
```